# How can I convert \uffffffc3\uffffffab to ë in python?

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding

I manipulate a JSON response that have a special encoding of unicode characters.

For example:

```
\uffffffc3\uffffffab = ë
```

What is this kind of encoding ?

How can I decode in python that response to traditional `utf-8` ?

Thanks,

Comment: Two problems spring to mind: JSON only defines `\uXXXX` (four hexadecimal digits), and Unicode itself only goes up to 0x10FFFF.  That's just invalid JSON.

Comment: Split to byte-string converting from 32-bit to 8-bit, and use `.decode('utf-8')`: `b'\xc3\xab'.decode('utf-8')`

Comment: Please [edit] to show how you got \uffffffc3\uffffffab.